# cannot be resolved or is not a field , R.string.kws_caption

Tags: java, android

I'm doing an android project to create  speech recognition. compiler shows me 2 error:

```
forecast_caption cannot be resolved or is not a field
kws_caption cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Here is part of my code:
package com.example.pocket_sphinx;

```
import com.example.pocket_sphinx.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
.
.
.
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {
    private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
    private static final String DICTATION_SEARCH = "digits";
    private static final String KEYPHRASE = "oh mighty computer";
        private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        // Prepare the data for UI
        captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
        captions.put(DICTATION_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                .setText("Preparing the recognizer");
.
.
.
}
```

I imported R but it still shows that kws_caption and forecast_caption cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Did you define your string resources?

Comment: Sometime but not always, having the line `import com.example.pocket_sphinx.R;` causes the error. Try removing that and compiling it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define strings, usually in `src/main/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="forecast_caption">...</string>
    <string name="kws_caption">...</string>
</resources>
```

It's possible that your `strings.xml` is in the wrong place and not being picked up by the resource compiler.

Also make sure that there's no

```
import android.R;
```